# What is the best way to perform several API requests in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, .net-core, restsharp

I have a problem to resolve at work.

I have a .NET application, where I need to make several requests, one after the other, to an endpoint in an API, however, this API has many request problems, and ends up returning many errors. I tried to keep trying to resend the request up to 5 times, but it still gives an error.

I believe that if I better structure the way I send requests and with a slightly longer interval, the chance of success increases.

How would you do it? Do you have any examples?

This is an example that I built:
(It is worth mentioning that I have a list, with more than 500 requests in a foreach, which will call the function below)

```
int numberOfTentatives = 0;
int timeOut = 5000;
Exception lastExpection = new Exception();

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Table_Price[] response = new Table_Price[0];
RestClient client = new RestClient(BasePath);
var request = new RestRequest($"api/url", Method.Get);
request.AddQueryParameter("sku", sku);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", token);
request.Timeout = -1;

while (numberOfTentatives < _maxTentatives)
{
    try
    {
        response = client.Get<Table_Price[]>(request);
        return response;
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        if (ex.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            token = $"Bearer {GetToken(_authRequest)}";
        }
        lastExpection = ex;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lastExpection = ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        numberOfTentatives++;
        timeOut += 100;
    }

    Thread.Sleep(timeOut);
}

_CFMContext.Insert_LOG_Error(BrasiliaTime(), $"GetPriceTable({sku})", $"002 - Unable to process api request after 5 attempts : {lastExpection.Message}");
return response;
}
```

Comment: I would start with asynchronous tasks if at all possible.  Then you can increase your timeout without exponentially delaying the entire collection processing.  Create a task for each item, add the task to an array (or collection and convert after), and do a Task.WaitAll() on that array at the end.

Comment: See [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly)

Comment: Please, I have some doubts regarding this. I don't particularly use asynchronous requests, so I don't have much knowledge about it.

So, my first question is: Even using asynchronous requests, can I wait for the response to register a log?

Do you have any code examples that have something similar?

Comment: When Unauthorized you want to change the token in the request right? That you are not doing now. (you are just assigning it a new value)

Comment: The problem is not in the authentication part, I just need a way to guarantee that all requests will be carried out successfully. Since the external API that I'm sending returns many errors.

Comment: But if you get Unauthorized retrying the same request again would result in the same result. You probably only want to retry the status code 500 range (Server errors)

Comment: Now I understand, it really is one more point that I can improve. Thanks!

Comment: [Docs](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#reusing-httpclient): _"RestSharp uses HttpClient internally to make HTTP requests."_ - So, I would suggest to either use one of the CTORs that allows you to reuse the same (and single) HttpClient instance or use just one RestClient instance. Otherwise you may see all the same problems when creating a new HttpClient for each call (which you do). RestSharp docs recommend [using a simple Client Factory](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#simple-factory).

Comment: BTW: You also don't dispose of the client here, which would not be a problem when reusing the client, but here, it may be at some point.

Comment: I would think that the best way would be to fix the API that cannot cope with the volume of requests. Can you add an endpoint that would let you get all the info in a single call? Or do you need someway to export the data?

Answer (score 1):

I would use Polly for the retry and spicify which status codes that should be handled. You can then use an exponential increase in the delay. (if you want)
And convert it to async.

```
var response =
     await 
         Policy
             .Handle<HttpRequestException>(ex => CodesToRetry(ex.StatusCode))
             .WaitAndRetryAsync(3, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)))
             .ExecuteAsync(async () =>
             {
                 return await client.GetAsync<Table_Price[]>(request);
             });
         

public static bool CodesToRetry(System.Net.HttpStatusCode? statusCode)
{
    return
        statusCode is 
            HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError or
            HttpStatusCode.BadGateway or
            HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable or
            HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout or
            HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout or
            HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests; //TooManyRequests you might want to handle differently. In the response it will tell you how long to wait before retrying.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know Polly, I'll test the code above.

But, let me see if i understand, "3" is the number of attempts ?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: No, 3 is the max retry count. In the worst case you have 4 attempts (the initial request and 3 retry attempts).

Comment: @PeterCsala Im pretty sure that is what he ment. "max retry count" == "number of attempts"